# REST API best practices: ignoring filter when empty

Tags: rest, api-design

In the scenario of a users API (`/api/users`) with a property of `team_id`, I want to set up an endpoint that allows me to get users with specific team IDs, i.e. `/api/users?team_ids=1&team_ids=2&team_ids=3`.

My question is, what if I want to ignore this filter?

For instance, if there's a multiselect dropdown in the UI and the user de-selects all team_ids, the expected result would be nothing as they have selected zero teams, and all users are in a team. From an API perspective however, I think it would be reasonable to expect that `/api/users` would return all users.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make that parameter required then, so if it doesn't exist the response is an empty array. Or you can limit the amount of users returned

Comment: Well the question is, how do I support both: a) Returning all users without requiring the API request to know all the team IDs, b) Returning users for the specified teams (which could be none)

Comment: You could use POST for search, and for all users use GET. There is no rules in REST that you have to save something with a POST request so it's fine to use POST for search or filtering

Comment: My goal is the share the REST API resource between the two, between a "GetAll" and a filtered/pagination request